# Does culture both reflect and create society?

Tags: sociology

It seems to me that if a culture represents a society's values and ideologies, then it is society that creates culture, and not the other way around. Take, for example, the 1960's civil rights movement. Ascribing to this paradox, the very culture that was responsible for keeping the African-American legally unequal is now responsible for making and keeping the African-American legally equal. Thus, I would argue that the primary reason our culture includes tolerance for others is because society modified its culture.

Comment: It is unclear to me what the philosophical problem is here. You seem to be asking a question and giving the answer yourself. If you are looking for a discussion with others, [this is not the place](http://meta.philosophy.stackexchange.com/q/474/2953), unfortunately. Can you clarify what your question is, within the bounds of the [help/on-topic]? Thanks!

Comment: Please note, it is acceptable to ask and answer your own question, if both are presented in a way of general interest.  The question and answer should be posted separately. The question should be detailed and focused, and the answer should be authoritatively sourced and cited (not just a matter of your personal opinion, no matter how good that opinion might be).  If you edit to improve your question, and remove your answer, it might be reopened.  You could then answer it.

Answer (score 3):

The two are interwined.

[Culture](http://plato.stanford.edu/entries/culture-cogsci/#WhaCul) consists of the beliefs, behaviors, objects, and other characteristics common to the members of a particular group or society.

And [society](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Society) can be defined as the people who interact in such a way as to share a common culture.

Thus, it is hard to define a one-way only "causal" relation between them.

Comment: I would say that a society is a group of interacting people and culture is the method by which they interact. Different cultures can often coexist in a single society.